# On a terminal services server windows 2008 how can you lower the security settings of users

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I'm trying this question again because apparently it didn't demonstrate enough effort to solve the problem, so I will list step by step what I have done and what is not working. If you are doubting the level of effort I have been back and forth on this problem for 2 days (other stuff did get in the way), and most every effort and finding something brings to documentation that is about a different server version, a different setup (generally with Active Directory) and precisely zero helpful information about what, in totality, actually has to be set to make this work.

The final result that I need is that for users the Internet Explorer security is set to Medium. This is because QuickBooks, which is what users use this server to run, insists on using IE and complains about the high settings, so our usual solution for working around the Windows IE security dance is not available (our usual solution being to just install Chrome for them).

The result has to include QuickBooks understanding that that is the setting.

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2, with terminal services enabled. There is no Active Directory involved on this server. The version of Internet Explorer is 11.0.2. We are primarily a linux shop on the server end and only have a small windows server for this purpose.

Using the local Group Policy Object editor, for a specific user (this is the current state, I have tried doing it for the Local Computer policy, in both the computer configuration and the user configuration) Under User Configuration/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Internet Control Panel/Security Page, the Lock-Down Internet Zone and the Internet Zone templates are set to enabled and to medium.

The user has logged out and logged back in to activate the policy (that is what I have found needs to be done, but I could be wrong about that).

A solution that lets the user edit the tab would be fine too, but I don't see that option anywhere. The inline description  on the Disable the Security page of the Internet Control Panel under "Security Zones: Do not allow users to change policies". I finally found that policy, and disabling it had no effect on the situation, so clearly something else is locking this, but I have no idea what.

At this point, the settings remain on high on the Tools->Options->Security tab from internet explorer for the user, and QuickBooks continues to detect them as high. The user remains unable to edit the security tab, even though there is no setting regarding disabling the security tab active (and I can't find a corresponding enabling the tab or giving the user rights to manipulate it).

All advice so far has generally been inaccurate, as it jumps to how things are under Active Directory - and they are not the same. The underlying setting or group policy structure *may* be the same, but that isn't obvious to me, and I don't accept that that level of familiarity is necessary to ask a question, especially when you could just as easily be dinged for lack of knowledge for getting it wrong.

So where is the setting (yes that comment got me in all the hot water on the last revision, but there it is again) to enable lower security in Internet Explorer for non-admin users or to allow users to set it themselves? I can't find it, and it is not for lack of trying, or because I don't understand system administration basics (although I will readily admit to not being an expert, and especially not in Windows Server system administration). The Group policy represents a tree of tens of thousands of settings, and it is not obvious what the right setting is.

[This user](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ee6b300-9d17-4501-97d8-6f700122a847/ie-security-zone-policy?forum=winserverGP) has the same type of problem, but no resolution is provided in that thread.

Running rsop.msc on a user account shows that the policy is enabled as expected. But the computer behavior doesn't match.

Comment: fwiw, *this* is a much, much better question that your previous version. Much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using Group Policy & the [Internet Explorer Maintenance Extension](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728150.aspx) for this.

1. Create a GPO for your IE settings, link it to the Terminal Services OU. (example: IE Terminal Server Settings)
2. Open GPO for IE settings
3. Navigate to:
   User Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\ Internet Explorer Maintenance\Security
4. Change settings and click OK.
5. Test by running gpupdate /force or have log off/on the Terminal Server.

For Local Group Policy on your server open up the Group Policy Object Editor. (Start > run > mmc > Add/Remove Snap-ins > Group Policy Object Editor)

Navigate to `\Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page` 
[image]

In the right pane you will see Internet Zone Template. Right click to edit the template. Select **Enable** and from the drop down you can select your security level setting. This same process works for the Intranet Zone as well. 
[image]

**Also** disabling IE Enhanced Security Configuration will allow you to change the Internet Zone. Server Manager > Configure IE ESC under Security Information:
[image]

Comment: "User Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\ Internet Explorer Maintenance\Security" is not available exactly under that name in Local Group Policy, and what is there is different enough that I can't find any corresponding setting.

Comment: @Yishai which version of IE is on your terminal server?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Comment: @Yishai I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that is the setting I was playing with, and it isn't helping (I tried again for now for good measure). I have to think that the Terminal Services has some sort of override for this, but I have no idea where to look to find it.

Comment: If you're applying those settings to the computer then you need to refresh group policy on the computer by running gpupdate /force on the computer. GPO settings for computers affect all users logging onto those computers but the settings won't take effect until group policy on the computer has been refreshed. Also, for QB running from an internal mapped network drive you probably need to set the setting in the Intranet zone, not the Internet zone.

Comment: @Yishai I was trying to get it to work myself with the local GPO. Disabling the IE ESC (added to answer) allows you to change the security level of the Internet zone.

Comment: @joeqwerty, Yes, and we even restarted the server last night (for an unrelated reason, a QuickBooks update I think). Didn't take.

Comment: @cole, That is actually an interesting data point. That setting is changed when you install terminal services automatically. I set it back to on, logged in, logged out, and set it to off. Now it shows medium-high instead of high. It seems to have also made some changes to the group policy on its own (playing with that setting). I'm investigating further. +1 for all the effort. Thanks for that, however it works out.

Comment: @cole, OK, My initial thought that group policy changed was based on an incorrect reading of the tree (too many roots, computer, user, non-administrator, that I had open on my console). However, the behavior did change. Quickbooks stopped complaining, and it is now Medium high. This all happened because of Changing IE ESC to on and then back to off. So Group Policies still don't work, but the problem is at least solved.